# How to fix the "pre-receive hook declined" error when trying to upload an existing git project to gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, repository

Our project was developed by another external company and hosted in their respective gitlab account.

Now they have passed us the source code and we want to upload it to our gitlab account.
We have created a private repository in gitlab for this.
This repository only has the admin user and is empty.

However, when doing `git push origin master` it gives us the following error:

```
[remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: some references to 'gitlab.com:sanduzelai/xxx.git' failed to push
```

How can we fix this error?

I've read similar questions on stackoverflow but haven't gotten it to work.
I have tried creating a branch from master and doing `git push` but it has not worked.
If I delete the **.git** folder and create it with the `git init` command the repository is successfully uploaded to gitlab.
However, I would like to keep the logs. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `master` is most probably protected and the user is not allowed to push. You could either unprotect master or grant the user the permission "allow to push" or update master through a merge request.

Comment: That's what I thought at first.
In the new gitlab account there is only my user (I have created it).
I understand that I must have all the permits.
I created a branch from master to try to upload the repository with it.
Could the problem come from the users of the external company who have made the previous commits and do not have permissions?

Comment: Does your GitLab project (or instance if self-managed) have a push rule requiring matching committer emails or verified/signed commits?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a different branch from master like develop using command below
git checkout -b develop
Then push your changes to the new branch
git push -uf origin develop

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider if the external company will "transfer" the project to you instead of a download/upload like what's being done, as that would preserve not only the repository history, but also any open issues on the project. If they (or you) run a self-hosted gitlab, you can also export and import the project to get the same approach.

That having been said, there are multiple things that can cause this type of an issue, but here are a couple of examples:

- If you're running a self-hosted gitlab, you may have server-side git hooks that are blocking the commit.
- If you're running on gitlab.com, you may have rules enabled that force a certain email to be used for pushing a commit, or you may require GPG signing of commits

You should likely send a note to your gitlab admin and determine what your setup is, and what may be blocking the commit.